# AD authentication sometimes failed using PHP LDAP

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently working on my company intranet community website. Staff here can post some news or notifications on the website which they need to login first using their AD Login Credentials before posting anything.

The problem is, the login functions sometimes work and sometimes not. I'm sure that i'm using the correct password for login. When it hits error, it will show invalid credentials. FYI, i'm using Apache with PHP 5.4.22 running in MS WIN Server 2003 R2.

Here is my code for login page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Intranet | Sharepoint - Login</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card card-login mx-auto mt-5">
      <div class="card-header">Login</div>
      <div class="card-body">


        <form action="ldap.php" id="login" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder= "eg: 031074" required>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder= "Your Windows Login Password" required>                    
            <br />
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>

        <div class="text-center">
          <br>
          <a class="d-block small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my authentication page:

```
<?php
// config
$ldapserver = '192.168.X.XXX';
$ldapuser      = 'thongguan\administrator';  
$ldappass     = 'XXXXXXX';
$ldaptree    = "OU=ThongGuanUser,DC=thongguan,DC=local";

// connect d
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if($ldapconn) {
// binding to ldap server
ldap_set_option( $ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );
ldap_set_option( $ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0 );


$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
// verify binding
if ($ldapbind) {
$result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(samaccountname=".$_POST["username"].")") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++) {
        //echo "dn is: ". $data[$i]["dn"] ."<br />";
        $usern= $data[$i]["cn"][0];
        if(isset($data[$i]["samaccountname"][0])) {
           // echo "ID: ". $data[$i]["samaccountname"][0] ."<br /><br />";
        } else {
           // echo "ID: None<br /><br />";
        }
    }
}
}


$ldap_dn = "cn=".$usern.",OU=ThongGuanUser,DC=thongguan,DC=local";
$ldap_password = $_POST["password"];

$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap://ADServer.thongguan.local");
ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password)){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["authenticated"] = 'true';
    header('Location: adminpanel.php');
    $userlog= $_POST["username"];
    $_SESSION["userlog"] = $userlog;
}
else{
    header('Location: login.php');
}?>
```

The problem is sometimes it can authenticate user, sometimes not. but running the same code on my local desktop PC works like charm all the time.

Hope someone can point out my mistake.

Comment: What error message do you get when it doesn't work?

Comment: no error message, just authentication failed